# What is the correct word order for a temperature sensor that is put on the skin but is able to estimate the core temperature?

Tags: word-order

Should it be "skin core temperature sensor" or "core temperature skin sensor"?

Comment: Google can't find results for either (exact) phrase.

Comment: I know, this is a new device :P

Comment: what about 'external core temperature sensor'?

Comment: that is more vague. that could be for example an infrared camera that estimates core temperature.

Comment: No, its a sensor that uses several thermometers, I cant call it thermomether

Comment: Is this some sort of invention that you have created? I feel like naming products is somewhat off-topic.

Comment: Definitely not the first one. That reads as if the device senses the core temperature *of skin*. I think the second one probably works. You might try hyphenating core-temperature for clarity.

Comment: You're assuming that there's always going to be a satisfactory way of stacking premodifiers to give unambiguous new compounds. Attributives in particular are used in a bewildering number of semantic roles ('skin' can obviously mean 'made from skin'). Is 'topical core temperature sensor' any better? Or is 'topical' restricted to describing _medications_ –  lotions, sprays etc – applied to the surface of the skin?

Comment: You should ask a doctor or med tech what he'd call it.

Comment: Separate "skin core" for clarity, since I'm pretty sure it's a skin sensor for reading core temperature. Now with that out of the way, consider clustering your nouns with some air in there for reader clarity: Skin sensor **for reading** core temperature. If you're stuck on the idea of four nouns, then the clearest order I see is *core temperature skin sensor*.

Comment: Yes I think Skin sensor to monitor core temperature would be my best bet

Comment: Seems like the issue here is that "skin" isn't really quite the right word... you really want a word that means "touches the skin". There's probably a proper medical term for that (which probably starts with "derm-"), but all I can think of is "contact" or "external"...

Comment: Both versions misstate the real nature of the thing. It's primarily an **estimator**, not a sensor. Anyone can slap a sensor in something. But that estimation algorithm is the real added value.

Comment: Don't ever write anything like this. It's horrible. Use a preposition, or two. e.g. Sensor for core skin temperature, or sensor for core temperature of the skin.

Answer (score 1):

How about use hyphens?

E.g. *skin-based core-temperature sensor*

Or a SBCTS to those in the field.

Comment: That almost kinda sorta works.

Answer (score 0):

How about switching words, as in *adhesive core temperature sensor*?

Comment: Yeah, I really want to know the core temperature of that adhesive!